# ReadFile function from WinApi does not read from CreateProcess with CreatePipe

Tags: c, winapi, readfile

I'm writing an application to obtain Geolocation on C.

To get the coordinates, I decided to use Popen with PowerShell and this is the code I wrote:

```
BOOL getLatitude(wchar_t* latitudeBuffer)
{
    enableLocation();
    FILE* latitudePipe;
    if (latitudePipe = _wpopen(L"powershell -c \"Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Device; $GeoCoordinateWatcher = New-Object System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinateWatcher; $GeoCoordinateWatcher.Start(); Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 2500; $GeoCoordinateWatcher.Position.Location.Latitude 2>&1\"", L"r"))
    {
        wchar_t* latitudeResult = fgetws(latitudeBuffer, COORDINATES_BUFFER_SIZE, latitudePipe);
        _pclose(latitudePipe);
        if (latitudeResult)
        {
            if ('0' <= latitudeBuffer[0] && latitudeBuffer[0] <= '9')
            {
                latitudeBuffer[COORDINATES_SIZE] = '\0';
                wchar_t* latitudePoint = wcschr(latitudeBuffer, L'.');
                if (latitudePoint != NULL) *latitudePoint = '-';
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
    }
    wcsncpy_s(latitudeBuffer, COORDINATES_BUFFER_SIZE, L"NULL", COORDINATES_BUFFER_SIZE);
    return FALSE;
}
```

It works, but I encountered a problem that when Popen is used, the terminal opens for a few seconds. And I need everything to happen in the background.

Then I decided to use `CreatePipe` and `CreateProcess`, and then read the output using `ReadFile`, but it did not put the result in the buffer and ended up in an infinite loop. Here's the code:

```
#define COORDINATES_BUFFER_SIZE 4096

void getLat(wchar_t* latitudeBuffer)
{
    enableLocation();
    
    HANDLE latitudeWriteOutHandle = NULL;
    HANDLE latitudeReadOutHandle = NULL;

    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES latitudeSecurityAttributes;
    latitudeSecurityAttributes.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    latitudeSecurityAttributes.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    latitudeSecurityAttributes.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    CreatePipe(&latitudeReadOutHandle, &latitudeWriteOutHandle, &latitudeSecurityAttributes, 0);
    SetHandleInformation(&latitudeReadOutHandle, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);

    wchar_t cmd[] = L"powershell.exe -c \"Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Device; $GeoCoordinateWatcher = New-Object System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinateWatcher; $GeoCoordinateWatcher.Start(); Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 2500; $GeoCoordinateWatcher.Position.Location.Latitude 2>&1\"";
    STARTUPINFO latitudeStartUpInfo;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION latitudeProcessInformation;
    ZeroMemory(&latitudeStartUpInfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    ZeroMemory(&latitudeProcessInformation, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
    latitudeStartUpInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    latitudeStartUpInfo.hStdOutput = latitudeWriteOutHandle;     // edited
    latitudeStartUpInfo.hStdError = latitudeWriteReadOutHandle;  // edited
    latitudeStartUpInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    if (CreateProcess(NULL, cmd, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &latitudeStartUpInfo, &latitudeProcessInformation))
    {
        CloseHandle(latitudeProcessInformation.hThread);
        CloseHandle(latitudeProcessInformation.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(latitudeWriteOutHandle);
        
        DWORD dwRead;
        while (TRUE) if (ReadFile(latitudeReadOutHandle, latitudeBuffer, COORDINATES_BUFFER_SIZE, &dwRead, NULL)) break;
        CloseHandle(latitudeReadOutHandle);
        wprintf(L"%s\n", latitudeBuffer);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. To read the coordinate, one iteration of `ReadFile` is enough for me.

Comment: What a horrifically convoluted way of calling a native API from native code. I've seen bad, really bad, but this is a new low.

Comment: One thing I have different in some code of mine is the close of `hProcess` is late, after the `ReadFile` is done.   You may also want to wait for the process to finish (`WaitForSingleObject`) after the read.

Comment: Windows is not linux where you call a command line tool to do the work for you and you pipe in and out. Use ILocation.

Comment: I see a lack of adequate error handling. You are not verifying if `CreatePipe()` is successful, but more importantly you are not breaking the reading loop if `ReadFile()` fails. "*To read the coordinate, one iteration of ReadFile is enough for me*" - then there is no point in using a loop at all. Ether you get the data or you don't. That said, why are you not simply using the `GeoLocation` object directly? You shouldn't need to shell out to PowerShell if the object is accessible to native languages via WinRT or COM.

Comment: Remy Lebeau can you tell me how to use object `GeoLocation` in C?

Comment: You were already given [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77982534/does-c-c-winapi-have-functions-for-getting-latitude-and-longitude#comment137478737_77982534) to sample code. Doing this in C is rather challenging, as it requires that you know COM inside and out.

Comment: @IInspectable Not "inside and out". The "out" is sufficient here. You just have to know how to invoke a vtable method from C, and even then, the system headers give you helper macros. It's just annoying because the C type names are ugly because they are basically decorated C++ type names.

Comment: @RaymondChen You'll also need to know the inside (not the inside of COM, but the Windows Runtime). Specifically, how to discover the activation factory and how to activate a type. Much of this can be hidden with a C++ library (indeed, all of it, in the case of C++/WinRT).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally realized what was wrong in my code.
First, I want to thank Ben Voigt for the correct answer.
So here is the code that started working for me.

```
HANDLE latitudeWriteOutHandle = NULL;
HANDLE latitudeReadOutHandle = NULL;

SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES latitudeSecurityAttributes;
latitudeSecurityAttributes.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
latitudeSecurityAttributes.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
latitudeSecurityAttributes.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

if (CreatePipe(&latitudeReadOutHandle, &latitudeWriteOutHandle, &latitudeSecurityAttributes, 0))
{
    SetHandleInformation(latitudeReadOutHandle, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);
    //                   ^ - no link needed here
    wchar_t cmd[] = L"powershell.exe -c \"Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Device; $GeoCoordinateWatcher = New-Object System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinateWatcher; $GeoCoordinateWatcher.Start(); Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 2500; $GeoCoordinateWatcher.Position.Location.Latitude 2>&1\"";
    STARTUPINFO latitudeStartUpInfo;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION latitudeProcessInformation;
    ZeroMemory(&latitudeStartUpInfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    ZeroMemory(&latitudeProcessInformation, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
    latitudeStartUpInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    latitudeStartUpInfo.hStdOutput = latitudeWriteOutHandle;
    latitudeStartUpInfo.hStdError = latitudeWriteOutHandle;
    latitudeStartUpInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    if (CreateProcess(NULL, cmd, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &latitudeStartUpInfo, &latitudeProcessInformation))
    {
        CloseHandle(latitudeProcessInformation.hThread);
        CloseHandle(latitudeProcessInformation.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(latitudeWriteOutHandle);
        char latitudeBuffer[COORDINATES_BUFFER_SIZE];
        DWORD dwRead;
        if (ReadFile(latitudeReadOutHandle, latitudeBuffer, COORDINATES_BUFFER_SIZE, &dwRead, NULL)) {
            //       ^ - no link needed here too
            printf("%s\n", latitudeBuffer);
        }
    }
}
```

Also for the buffer you need to use `char` instead of `wchar_t`.

Comment: Please explain what the problem is, so that the next person with this issue knows what to fix. I did a diff of the question and the answer, and found the only changes were to error checking. So where was the actual problem?

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the wrong end of the pipe to the child.

```
latitudeStartUpInfo.hStdOutput = latitudeReadOutHandle;
latitudeStartUpInfo.hStdError = latitudeReadOutHandle;
```

should instead be

```
latitudeStartUpInfo.hStdOutput = latitudeWriteOutHandle;
latitudeStartUpInfo.hStdError = latitudeWriteOutHandle;
```

Comment: I fixed it, but still ReadFile doesn't read anything